# How to query data difference from __unicode__() function in Django

Tags: django, orm

I had a model:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
     menu_id=models.CharField(max_length=30)
     name_vi=models.CharField(max_length=80)
     name_en=models.CharField(max_length=80)

     def get_all_menu(self):
          return Menu.objects.all()

     def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name_vi

     class Admin:pass
```

when calling get_all_menu, I want it return a 2d array of menu model included 3 field: menu_id, menu_vi, menu_en. But it return name_vi only, the same of **unicode** function.

Can I query full 3 fields in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the **get_all_menu** method should be a Model Manager method instead of a Model method like you have it as it is a function that acts on the entire table, not a single row/instance:

```
class MenuManager(models.Manager):
    def get_all_menu(self):
      return self.objects.all()

class Menu(models.Model):
    objects = MenuManager()
```

So you now can use this to get all rows of the table:

```
Menu.objects.get_all_menu()
```

**Secondly**, the **unicode** function has nothing to do with queries. It's simply a function to help display a sensibile name for the object when you print it.

**Thirdly**, why do you want a 2d array returned when you query the database? When you perform a query, you are getting 3 objects back so you have a reference to all of their attributes/columns:

```
menus = Menu.objects.get_all_menus()
for menu in menus:
    print menu.menu_id
    print menu.name_vi
    print menu.name_en
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any point putting `get_all_menu` into a Manager, since it's identical to the manager's `all()` method. I *suspect* (although of course the OP doesn't tell us) that he/she wants to use that in the admin `list_display`, and of course is just seeing the unicode representation.

Comment: Agreed, I was just pointing out the difference between operating at the row level as opposed to the table level.